# Adding Virtual Directory under Microsoft Dynamics Crm 2011 in IIS

Tags: iis-7, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it in general considered bad practice to add a "Virtual Directory" under Microsoft Dynamics Crm 2011 in IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on your requirements.

The documentation highly recommends that you should extend CRM using Webresource such as HTML with JScript or Silverlight.

But for exceptional cases **YES** you can add a "Virtual Directory" under IIS and reference the address in CRM in an iFrame or whatever.

This disadvantage behind adding Virtual Directory is that whenever you export your solution from development environment to live environment is you should also export to live environment.

Answer (score 4):

> ...is it bad practice...?

Yes.

Regardless of your circumstances it is considered bad practice. It is unsupported as per SDK and therefore should be avoided. If you "need" to do this, redesign your proposed solution.

From the SDK:

> When developing new code, the recommendation is to use the Web
>   resources feature of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. For scenarios that
>   will not be satisfied by the Web resources feature, **create your Web
>   application *in its own application pool*** with its own web.config

Found the [relevant bit in the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx#Unsupported) that explicitly states it is unsupported:

> Creating an Internet Information Services (IIS) application inside the Microsoft Dynamics CRM website for any VDir and specifically within the ISV folder is not supported.

Comment: No problem Skuli - don't mind not getting the points, but if you are to deal with your deployment in the way it is intended to be used, I would recommend against the Virtual Directory route. Good luck :)